# drools workbench in cloudfoundry.

Tags: drools, kie, cloud-foundry, kie-workbench

I am trying to deploy drools workbench in cloudfoundry. I am not able to push a docker image to my company's CF env, but these docker images works in my local PCF Dev. 
So, I pushed a war file to my CF env.

```
cf push kie -p kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.4.0.Final-wildfly8.war -b jboss-buildpack-offline -m 2g -k 2g -t 180
```

the application is running in CF. But I am not sure how to get launch the application, to see login page and workbench. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Dockerfile for drools-workbench (https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/drools-workbench/~/dockerfile/) it appears to start the workbench using bin/start_drools-wb.sh file, however the JBoss buildpack appears to start the application using standalone.sh

Perhaps you should look at how the application should be started and adapt the start command.